# Forking a process

Tags: java, c, fork

I have a process that goes to the database and gets data. The complexities and my questions are as follow:

Some data comes from one data source and the rest come from the other data source. I was wondering once i start a process, i can create the object where in i will dump all the data and then fork ( as in C language). an send each process to different data source.

Question 1 : If i do something like fork, it updates both the dumping of data simultaneously right? i.e. if parent process is getting data from source A and dumping in Object O, and chil process is getting from B and dumping in Object O only, the O gets populated simultaneously right? It will not create two objects one with data from A and other with data from B. Also, the efficiency of this process lies in the multiprocessor systems only?

Question 2: Is there anything like this in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: Child processes don't share variables with the parent; each child would have its own separate object O, and nothing would go into the parent's. But threads *do* share variables, and can be used to do what you want.

Comment: @Wyzard How do the threads differ from forkde processes. if you can brief me. THanks.

Comment: Processes are isolated from each other; they can:only interact in limited ways, such as with [signals](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) and [sockets](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/:Berkeley_sockets). Threads are part of a single process, so they all have direct access to that process's memory.

Comment: It's possible for processes to share some memory with each other, but they have to establish the sharing specially, and Java doesn't support it. Threads share all their memory automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the java equivalent to fork is `java.lang.Thread`. Have a look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for a tutorial.

If I understand the question correctly, it looks like access to DataSource A would be via the main thread of your application while access to DataSource B would be handled by a separate thread. I'd be tempted to push access to **both** datasources in to separate threads, wait for them both to finish, ( see [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) ), and then combine the results in to a single object ( Object O in your description above ).

Comment: Why do i need to combine the results, what if i have a single object O where the final data is to be dumped, now as both the threads work, wont they just keep filling the Object O on their own, and then at the end when both have finished dumping, i will get the Complete Data in the same Object O?

Comment: You _could_ have a single object, and get each thread to populate it. But you'd have to be very sure that the two threads couldn't overwrite each others results. I prefer combining the results after the event as it gives a better separation of concerns, and I think it also makes the code more maintainable in the long term. If you are using Java 7, you should probably look at @aviad's answer - it'll save you a bit of work ( disclaimer - I've not used the framework, just skimmed the tutorial )

Comment: It depends on what kind of object you use for storing the results: everything would go fine unless you run into update collisions (think of the case when the object you use is map and both thread will try to update the same entry simultaneously...) You will need to choose your storage object type carefully. There are several several thread-safe wrappers for java collections: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try what @DaveHoves suggested. 
Another option I personally prefer when dealling with multiple source data loading/processing would be using [ForkJoin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework. 
Please find good tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html).

Good Luck!

Comment: maybe you can refer to the comment i posted on DaveHoves answer. Thanks.